# access VBA programming how to renumber a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

Well i'm quite newbie to ACCESS . In my database there is a field i wish to use for sorting purposes .I would like a VBA script that makes the following . 
If i highlight a record (table view) and execute the function it does the following .It adds a new record to the database with same values as the highlighted except the sorting field which is incremented by one .
Finally the function modifies incrementing by one the sort field of all records whose sort number is equal or  higher than the  added  record sort number.
Is it too difficult what i'm asking ?. I tried autonumber but it's not editable so i can have the  specific sort order i want. Can somebody give me a code sample ?.Is there an easier way to do that? 
Any help would be appreciated

Michael

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post any code you've already tried writing to solve the problem. You shouldn't expect people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this (perhaps data macros?) but I suggest you do the following:

1. Create a form with your records, either with continuous view and with a form header/footer, or as an unbound form with the records in a subform in datasheet view.
2. Add a button to the form header/footer, which will run your macro

Your macro should do the following:

1. Save the currently selected row's sort field value.
2. Begin a transaction
3. Execute an `UPDATE` statment to update all the successive sort field values.
4. Take values from the current record and embed them into an `INSERT` statement, preferably with parameters. The `INSERT` should put the saved sort field value into the new record. Execute the `INSERT`.
5. End the transaction.